# QuickFix Market Data Message Error

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am new to fix. I am using quick fix library in my app. Im able to do logon and exchange heart beat. When i send the marketdata request, im getting the response from the server.  But my application is sending reject message to fix, when it receives a message. And so im not able to process the message. Below are the incoming and outgoing message.

```
20160623-11:19:45.898 : 8=FIX.4.49=24235=X34=12049=CfhDemoPrices52=20160623-11:19:46.41456=PrimoDEMOFIX262=PrimoApp123268=2279=1269=0278=30/23-14404955=GBPUSD270=1.48854271=1500000290=164=20160627279=1269=1278=30/23-14405455=GBPUSD270=1.48885271=1000000290=110=004
20160623-11:19:45.924 : 8=FIX.4.49=13735=334=12249=PrimoDEMOFIX52=20160623-11:19:45.92256=CfhDemoPrices45=12058=Tag not defined for this message type371=55372=X373=210=140
```

and below is how i subscribe for market data:

```
        QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest msg = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest();

        // Fill message fields
        msg.SetField(new MDReqID("PrimoApp123"));
        msg.SetField(new SubscriptionRequestType('1'));
        msg.SetField(new MarketDepth(1));
        msg.SetField(new MDUpdateType(1));

        // Add the MDEntryTypes group
        QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup noMDEntryTypes = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup();
        noMDEntryTypes.SetField(new MDEntryType('0'));
        msg.AddGroup(noMDEntryTypes);

        // Add the NoRelatedSym group
        QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup noRelatedSym = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup();
        noRelatedSym.SetField(new Symbol("GBPUSD"));
        msg.AddGroup(noRelatedSym);

        // Send message
        Session.SendToTarget(msg, FeederApp.mysession);
```

Please help me with this if possible

Answer (score 0):

Did you even look at what your reject message says?

```
45=120   // RefSeqNum - seq num of message that was rejected
58=Tag not defined for this message type
371=55   // RefTagID - tag 55 is the problem
372=X    // RefMsgType - the rejected message was an X (MarketDataIncrementalRefresh)
373=2    // SessionRejectReason 2=[TagNotDefinedForThisMessageType]
```

So according to this, the problem is that your DataDictionary is not configured to expect tag 55 (Symbol) inside of message type X.

However, that doesn't appear to be entirely accurate.  If you're pasted message is correct, it breaks down like this:

```
8 =FIX.4.4
9 =242
35 =X
34 =120
49 =CfhDemoPrices
52 =20160623-11:19:46.414
56 =PrimoDEMOFIX
262 =PrimoApp123
268 =2     // 2 MDEntry Sequences
  279 =1   // 1st sequence
  269 =0
  278 =30/23-144049
  55 =GBPUSD     // this looks ok here...
  270 =1.48854
  271 =1500000
  290 =1
  64 =20160627  // what?  this doesn't belong here!

  279 =1   // 2nd sequence
  269 =1
  278 =30/23-144054
  55 =GBPUSD
  270 =1.48885
  271 =1000000
  290 =1

10=004
```

Therefore, I suspect that either (1) you made an error when you copy/pasted your message, or (2) it's actually field 64 that is your problem.

**Next Steps:**

1) Read this page to learn how to customize the DataDictionary:
http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html

2) Get documentation from your counterparty and make sure your DataDictionary reflects all the field/message customizations that they have added to their system.

Comment: Thanks. Sry. Im new to this. And was not able to find any other help. the below are the message in  getting. I dont know what to edit in datadictinary. I downloaded the fix44.xml from internet and using that.

Comment: These are the fix messages  20160623-15:48:46.532 : 8=FIX.4.49=22035=W34=18649=CfhDemoPrices52=20160623-15:48:47.48356=PrimoDEMOFIX55=GBPUSD262=PrimoApp123268=2269=0270=1.48007271=1000000290=164=20160627278=30/25-723036269=1270=1.48032271=1500000290=1278=30/25-72304110=113
20160623-15:48:46.558 : =FIX.4.49=12835=334=18849=PrimoDEMOFIX52=20160623-15:48:46.55756=CfhDemoPrices45=18658=Tag appears more than once371=278372=W373=1310=000

Comment: Stop blindly pasting FIX messages to me without demonstrating that you tried to learn something.  Did you read the link that I gave you?  Did you attempt to get documentation about this connection from your counterparty?

Comment: Yes i did. Here are the things i dont get, the data coming in has the tag 268 as 2, which means it has two messages. but my fix application throws error as tag 278 appears more than once. I checked the data dictionary and im able to find these fields under a group. So what am i missing here. My fix app is not considering it as repeated message. I understand that. But im not sure what to change in fix dictionary to fix this

Comment: Do you have `UseDataDictionary=Y` and `DataDictionary=/path/to/your/xml` in your config?  It sounds like you might not have these set.

Comment: I have both the entries in the config, Still getting same error.UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=E:/Projects/Primo/FIX44.xml

Comment: Again: Did you attempt to get documentation about this connection from your counterparty?  Tag 64 looks like a message customization; the default DD will not expect that tag in that location in your message.  Surely there are other customizations as well.  Your DD will need to be edited to match your counterparty's specification.

Comment: Thanks. My counterparty is not ready to share their DD. i have narrowed down the problem to some extend  Please look into this link, it will show the exact problem im  facing          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014375/field-missing-in-quickfix-marketdataincrementalfullrefresh

Comment: They may not have a DD file for you, but they MUST have some specs.  If they cannot tell you what messages/fields they're going to send you, then they will be impossible to work with.  This would be very unusual.  (Can you tell me who they are?)

Comment: 278 is your problem.  I didn't realize that it didn't belong to `W` messages. I'm answering [your other question](stackoverflow.com/questions/38035838/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-group-in-quickfix) right now.